# Why do tab delimited files take less space than comma separated?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, csv

I've noticed that the same data, stored in a tab separated file, seems to take less space than when that data is stored in a comma separated file.

My first thought was that tab characters take more space than comma characters, but everything I can find indicates they take the same amount of disk space in UTF/Ascii.

Comment: depending on csv data, the comma separator may force the csv saving to enclose data (if they contain comma) while tab is less frequent so no enclosing needed when saving data.

Comment: I use tsv b/c tsv looks cooled than csv and it makes way more sense using tab separated values... if you open it up in text-edit you can interpret it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CSV version probably has "quotes" around the data fields (just in case they contain commas themselves).

Comment: Interesting and possibly related - https://ronaldduncan.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/text-file-formats-ascii-delimited-text-not-csv-or-tab-delimited-text/